# I want to show date (dd-mm-yyyy) format

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

In my table currently shows   `2019-01-21` this format  and i want to show `21-01-2019` like this

I am trying like this

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>DOB</th>
</tr>

 <?php foreach($employees as $post){?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $post->user_date_of_birth;?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: use date() function with strtotime for formatting date. eg- date(d-m-YY, strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth))

Comment: <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth));?></td>

Comment: on a personal matter, use yyyy-mm-dd or dd.mm.yyyy. please. there are too many non-standardised datum formats out there, help keep their count low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's assume that the `user_date_of_birth` has a value of `2019-01-21`

**Let's use your code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($employees as $post){?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth));?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
    Please set format in sql like this.

    SELECT FORMAT(FieldName,'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth));
```

Comment: 'd-m-Y' should be the format

Comment: Sorry my bad ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
<?php
    $yourDate = "2019-01-21";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($yourDate) );
?>
```

Output: **21-01-2019**

Then your final code will be like this

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>DOB</th>
</tr>

 <?php foreach($employees as $post){?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth));?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth));?></td>`

Comment: one `)` is missed in your answer

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post->user_date_of_birth));?></td>
```

Read more [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>DOB</th>
</tr>

 <?php foreach($employees as $post){ 
 $datetime=$post->user_date_of_birth;
        $timeformat = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($datetime));   ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $timeformat; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should to manage this in programming side, like `$origDate = "2018-04-20";

```
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($origDate));
echo $newDate;`
```